# Elasticsearch offline indexing using lucene with in 1 node 1 shard

Tags: java, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I have a 20mn data, each record size is 1kb, I wanted to create a lucene index which should be read by elasticsearch with one node and one shard. I wanted to know is there any chance that we can do this?

Comment: any good reason why you can't index it with ES?

Comment: @xeye i wanted to do the offline indexing.

Comment: @xeye because now i can index 1mn in 2 min using lucene  wid in my hardware conf. with es it took 6 min to index the 1mn. anyway i solved this and i am able index with lucene inside elasticsearch index.